# ruamel.yaml formatting of TimeStamp after deepcopy seems broken

Tags: python, timestamp, python-2.x, ruamel.yaml

```
import copy
import ruamel.yaml

d = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load("foo: 2016-10-12T12:34:56\n", preserve_quotes=True)
d2 = copy.deepcopy(d)
assert ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(d) == "foo: 2016-10-12T12:34:56\n"
assert ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(d2) == "foo: 2016-10-12 12:34:56\n"
```

I've got a function that needs to `deepcopy` its argument dict because it's planning to make changes to some nested keys. But when I `deepcopy` the `OrderedDict` returned from `ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load`, it loses some sort of metadata that apparently is needed in order to print `TimeStamp` datatypes correctly.

I'm looking for *either* an option I could pass to `round_trip_dump` to force it to print TimeStamps in the above format (with `T` instead of space), *or* a way to deepcopy a ruamel.yaml return value without breaking its metadata.

Comment: ruamel.yaml 0.13.8, with a fix for this, is now available, thanks for reporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ruamel.yaml` version 0.13.3, `__deepcopy__` was added to `CommentedMap` and `CommentedSeq` (in `comments.py`) but it was not added to `TimeStamp` (in `timestamp.py`), and that `__deepcopy__` for `TimeStamp` is what you need.

You can do either of two things:

1. add the following to your code before making the call to `copy.deepcopy()`:

   ```
   from ruamel.yaml.timestamp import TimeStamp

   def ts__deepcopy__(self, memo):
       ts = TimeStamp(self.year, self.month, self.day, 
                      self.hour, self.minute, self.second)
       ts._yaml = copy.deepcopy(self._yaml)
       return ts

   if not hasattr(TimeStamp, '__deepcopy__'):
       TimeStamp.__deepcopy__ = ts__deepcopy__
   ```
2. wait for version 0.13.8 to come out

The test with `hasattr()` in the first option makes sure you are not overwriting that method once it will be added (in the next release).

Comment: Actually I'm using `ruamel.yaml==0.12.5`, so I guess it wouldn't have all that stuff that was added in 0.13.3 either; but I tried this workaround and it worked for me even in 0.12.5. Thanks!

Comment: Originally I had suggested a first option to do, which was rolling back ot pre 0.13.2, but I realised through testing that that was not the problem. I deleted that option, but forgot to review the intro lines.